# cartoon application with jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I would like to make an educational mobile application, ie cartoon appreciation , using jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap. Is there one plugin or tutorial on how I can start my application?

Comment: you should learn html5 ;)

Comment: then all what you have to do is going to the documentation of phonegap and good luck :) http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/index.html

Comment: thank you, but i need a tuto to start :)

Comment: Do you need a basic tutorials or a specific one?

Comment: specific tuto of cartoon animation (interact with user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following links may be helpful for you,

[HTML5 Mobile Web Canvas animation using Phonegap + Kinetic.JS](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/html5-mobile-web-canvas-animation-using-phonegap-kinetic-js/)

[HTML5 Gaming](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davrous/archive/2011/07/21/html5-gaming-animating-sprites-in-canvas-with-easeljs.aspx)

[Improving Animation Performance in HTML5 Canvas](http://ramkulkarni.com/blog/improving-animation-performance-in-html5-canvas/)

Hope its helped